# How do I use Eclipse for Scheme development?

Tags: eclipse, scheme

Has anyone succeeded in running and debugging Scheme with Eclipse?

I've tied several plug-ins (scheme 48, schemeway) and couldn't get them working. I'm not sure why they won't work; I downloaded an interpreter (`kawa`, `mit-scheme`) and tried to configure it in the plugin but nothing happened (except that `mit-scheme` threw some errors).

I know there is another way - Racket, but I prefer not to use another IDE. I work with many languages and I'd like to be able to use one IDE for all of them.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**:
I tried to run the simplest .scm file (that has only (+ 1 1) in it). By configuration of the plug-ins I mean that I choose an external interpreter and then choose the kawa/mit-scheme interpreter exe file. When I choose kawa with schemeway it open a new window and waited for my input (I didn't have any input - JUST wanted to run the file...). When I did it with mit-scheme interpreter I got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21804689/getting-unbound-variable-with-scheme-48-in-eclipse-and-mit-scheme-interpreter) error...
I am using linux-centOS 6.

Comment: It might be helpful to outline how you tried to configure those plugins, and what errors you got out of `mit-scheme`. I can't help you with the problem I'm afraid; I don't use Eclipse for any of the languages I usually work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution - here it is if someone else will encounter the same error:

There are 2 step when trying to work with Scheme 48 in Eclipse:

1. install the plugin - just follow http://s48.org/sdt/
2. install the interpreter - I finally found 2 that I can work with :

   1. Scheme 48 (I use ubuntu so I typed scheme48 in the command line and it gave me the package that I need to install (I think it was
      `sudo apt-get install scheme48`)). Then open the preferences in
      Eclipse and    go to scheme48->interpreter and check that the
      command line is    scheme48.
   2. guile - I think that it is supported by gnu. It also the one I prefer. It had less errors and more understandable error output in the consul. Again, to install it I just typed guile in the command line and it gave me 3 versions. I installed 1.8. after installation I created a scheme project and a simple file. go to the preferences and changed the command line to "guile" and the working directory to the path of the project I just created. to load the file just search for the load file into interpreter button (or press *Ctrl+F6*).